Is my code causing deadlock ? I'm not sure. Could someone confirm or disconfirm?
For a new project at my new job, the tech lead and architect asked me to learn and use boost::asio. Specifically the class thread_pool of the library.
Let me put things in context.
We are building an application that will make complex calculations. The user sends an XML as input with all the data that we need inside and the project I'm developping, should take that XML, retrieve all the infos it needs and then, launch and execute a bunch of calculations. Finally, the result must be sent back to the user. This is all done asynchronously.
Now, the architect wants the project to be a micro service taking requests from the users.
And in order to make as many calculations as possible, we should have a thread pool of calculators.
Each thread would dig into the queue of requests by users. Make the calculcation, return the result and if the queue is not empty, then take the next request. To accomplish this, Boost Asio was chosen. So, my question is really specific to Boost Asio. We don't intend to change the tool.
Boost asio contains a class thread_pool that seems to be designed to solve this kind of problems.
I'm still at the beginning phase and I tried to see how it works. Unfortunately, even this simple code that I wrote today, seems not working all the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it hang and nothing happens....which for me is a sign of deadlock. I'm not sure.
Could you tell me please what's the issue with it ?
Cheers,
#include <boost/asio/post.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool{5};
    std::mutex mutex;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        boost::asio::post(pool, [i, &mutex]() {
            try
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mutex};
                std::cout << "Task " << i << " executed by thread " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                          << std::endl;
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        });
    }

    std::future<int> r1 = boost::asio::post(pool, boost::asio::use_future([]() { return 2; }));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mutex};
        std::cout << "Result = " << r1.get() << '\n';
    }

    // Optional: Wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I ran the code and sometimes everything is ok but other times, it just hang and nothing happens.

You acquire the mutex in your main thread and wait for the last task to finish. The last task likely won't get the chance to execute before the first five tasks finish, since your thread_pool is limited to 5 threads. The problem stems from the fact that your main thread might acquire the lock before any of the jobs start executing, and this would prevent the first 5 tasks from finishing in the first place, which would in turn prevent the last task from starting.

Thanks so much @Violet! I was able to understand the bad logic of my code with your explanation.

Yes. The deadlock potential exists because you do a blocking wait on the future in main: r1.get() while holding the console output mutex. If you wait OUTSIDE the lock, the deadlock potential is gone: Live On Coliru:
r1.wait();
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{console_mx};
    std::cout << "Result = " << r1.get() << '\n';
}

Note, using std::osyncstream instead avoids the pitfall altogether: Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

static thread_local unsigned const thread_id = [] {
    static std::atomic<unsigned> id = 0;
    return id++;
}();

static auto out() { return std::osyncstream{std::cout}; }

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool pool{5};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        post(pool, [i] { out() << "Task " << i << " executed by thread " << thread_id << std::endl; });

    std::future<int> r1 = post(pool, asio::use_future([]() { return 2; }));

    // r1.wait();
    out() << "Result = " << r1.get() << '\n';

    pool.join();
}



This is really nice. Thanks so much. And I learnt about the std::osyncstream. Unfortunately, the project is for the moment only C++17 but we might migrate to C++23 next year. So I'll keep that in mind.

If you don't want to change the paradigm of your code, just move getting the result of executing "future" beyond mutex_lock:
std::future<int> r1 = boost::asio::post(pool, boost::asio::use_future([]() { return 2; }));
{
    int res = r1.get(); // move r1.get outside the lock
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mutex};
    std::cout << "Result = " << res << '\n';
}


I should have done that indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Arguably, getting and storing the value is changing the paradigm of the code more than simply waiting for the future to be ready first. I don't really see what else is different from my answer.

@sehe, I prefer your answer because it is more detailed and you cleaned my code a bit. the code here is just the one that I should have thought of for my quick tests for learning. But yours is really the way I should do thing in a more general way (use of thread_local, atomics, osynstream). Hope this makes senses.

@anthonyNk Yeah clear :) I was mainly wondering how user3811082 thinks this answer is "changing the paradigm" less. No worries.

Because your answer takes away the author's control over the mutex, which may have been important to him. Perhaps, over time, he would have added rw_lock or other ways to control the protected I/O. For me, this is a change in the author's logic, since you are thus redesigning the code. I did just a minor refactoring of the code, leaving the choice to the author)

@user3811082 I think you have misread the answer? My answer suggests waiting for the future to be ready. As an aside it also shows how syncstream alleviates some need to keep this in mind.
